# Camera fails to start on Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu Edition

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, camera

I have just got my new Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu Edition. However, the Camera app crashes at startup.

OTA-11 has not appeared yet to install. Is it a known bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OTA 11 has resolved this problem. Camera works now.